# A average Mark overall for all of one student subjects

Tags: mysql, query

Lets say  i have a student table , a enlistment table that shows SubjectId and Results for each student  how would i get the overall average mark for a student that has more than 3 subjects

```
Create table  a_Student(
StudentId int(5) Not null,
StudentForename varchar (30) Not null,
StudentSurname varchar (45) Not null, 
PRIMARY KEY(StudentId)
);
Create table a_Enlistment(
StudentId int(5) Not null,
SubjectId char(6) Not null,
results char (2),
primary key (SubjectId,StudentId),
foreign key (SubjectId) references a_Subject(SubjectId),
foreign key (StudentId) references a_Student(StudentId)
);


insert into a_Student (StudentId,StudentForename,StudentSurname)
values ("33447","Alan","Burns"),
("33672","Mark","Harrison",); 


 Insert into a_Enlistment (StudentId,SubjectId,Results)
values  
        ("33447","TMP243","78"),
         ("33447","AWD169","45"),
         ("33447","IIA887","48"),
        ("33672","TMP243","57"),
       ("33672","AWD169","67"),
      ("33672","IIA887","48"),
```

So i want lets say Alans overall mark for his 3 subjects  how would i do that?
Any help is welcomed thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

you can use a subquery to get the result for average and the number of subjects

> ```
> Create table  a_Student(
> StudentId int(5) Not null,
> StudentForename varchar (30) Not null,
> StudentSurname varchar (45) Not null, 
> PRIMARY KEY(StudentId)
> );
> ```

> ```
> Create table a_Enlistment(
> StudentId int(5) Not null,
> SubjectId char(6) Not null,
> results char (2),
> primary key (SubjectId,StudentId),
> #foreign key (SubjectId) references a_Subject(SubjectId),
> foreign key (StudentId) references a_Student(StudentId)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into a_Student (StudentId,StudentForename,StudentSurname)
> values ("33447","Alan","Burns"),
> ("33672","Mark","Harrison");
> ```

> ```
>  Insert into a_Enlistment (StudentId,SubjectId,Results)
> values  
>         ("33447","TMP243","78"),
>          ("33447","AWD169","45"),
>          ("33447","IIA887","48"),
>         ("33672","TMP243","57"),
>        ("33672","AWD169","67"),
>       ("33672","IIA887","48"),
>       ("33672","test","52")
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT s.*
> ,avgresults
> FROM a_Student s INNER JOIN (SELECT
> StudentId,
> AVG(Results) avgresults,
> COUNT(*) countr FROM a_Enlistment
> GROUP BY StudentId) e ON s.StudentId = e.StudentId
> WHERE countr > 3
> ```
>
> ```
> StudentId | StudentForename | StudentSurname | avgresults
> --------: | :-------------- | :------------- | ---------:
>     33672 | Mark            | Harrison       |         56
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94519faef3a90604877824a43b544f74)*